# Pascal understanding

Tags: delphi, freepascal

So assume this code work.

```
{***Start declaration of TMakeProd ***}

TListMakeProd = class (TListNF)
  procedure SortProcProdSeqNum;
  procedure LoadFromRep(aFileRep, aNo : String);
  function Find(aMakeProdID : Integer) : TMakeProd;
  function FindObj(aMakeProd : TMakeProd) : TMakeProd;
end;

TMakeProd = class (TProduct)
private
  FMakeProductID : Integer;
  FProdLotSize : Longint;

public
  LiProcProd : TListProcProd;
            {Load from a database.}
 { procedure SortLiProcProdSeqNum;   }
  constructor Init(aMakeProductID: Integer; aProdLotSize: Longint);
  destructor Done; override;
  destructor Destroy;  override;
  property MakeProductID : Integer read FMakeProductID write FMakeProductID ;
  property ProdLotSize : Longint read FProdLotSize write FProdLotSize ;
  function findNextProcProd(aProcProd: TProcProd) : TProcProd;

{ create function with return if required. }
end;
```

What I don't understand is this declaration `LiProcProd : TListProcProd;`
I know that `TListProcProd` is a class, everything else I understand it but this part I don't also this is just a class declaration and assume all the class have been properly declared

Comment: It's just a public property, what's to understand?

Comment: @et1975 Public *field*, right? Not property, as it doesn't have read/write qualifiers, the `property` keyword, and a field backing it up (except itself, obviously)

Comment: I don't know the pascal I didn't understod that was a variable declaration of class type x) thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
type
  TMakeProd = class(TProduct)
  ....
    LiProcProd : TListProcProd;
  ....
  end;
```

In this declaration, `LiProcProd` is a public field. This is described by the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fields).